# Git - Remote site to local

Tags: git, data-synchronization

I have a new client wordpress site, which was built in a bit of a mess (but it works).

I have installed Git on the remote server and on my local machine.

Before I start developing locally, I need all documents from remote server copied to my local server.

How do I do this using Git please?

I am a git noob, so please go easy on me... Is it as simple as...

REMOTE SERVER:

```
git commit -m "Initial Pull"
```

LOCAL SERVER:

```
git pull website master
```

I know I can just copy files over using FTP, but I wish to have the local and remote servers to be synched / Version Controlled before I start coding away.

Or have I completely misunderstood the purpose of Git?

Update:

assuming that my username is harry and my server domain name is potter.co.uk and the git repository is in /home/harry/site.git could you confirm if this will work? Will I break anything if I try this out on my local machine?

```
git clone harry@potter.co.uk:/home/potter/site.git
```

Comment: git clone will not change anything on server machine, it merely make a copy on your local machine.

Comment: BTW, I think the correct comamnd is `git clone ssh://harry@potter.co.uk:55555/home/potter/site.git` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), in which the 55555 is the port you open (remove :55555 if you have no idea about it), and ssh should be changed to the protocol you configured. (Normally it is configured to be ssh)

Comment: your cmd would be git clone harry@potter.co.uk:site.git unless of course the repo is in the user potter's home dir and not harry's dir.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use git clone

> git clone username@server:path/to/repo.git

If you are going to be working with several repos, I would add an entry to your ~/.ssh/config file

```
Host git
HostName myserver.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
User mygituserid
```

Then you can just do

> git clone git:/path/to/repo.git

In either case, remember that the path after the : is relative to the ssh user's home dir without a leading /

Also, if you want to push back changes to REMOTE the remote repo should be bare. To convert to a bare execute (as per @jthill's comment)

```
git clone --mirror existing_repo repo.git
```

Then i would clone that new,bare repo to my local machine before beginning work.

Comment: Thanks, but does that mean that my git repository needs to be in the public html folder? Is that secure or is this a dumb question?

Comment: no, i wouldn't put the git repo in the webroot. It's through ssh

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the advice scott. could you check my updated question then please...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the cd/cp/cd/config sequence above can be done with `git clone ==mirror path/to/this path/to/that`.

Comment: @jthill I wasn't aware of the --mirror option. That works much better than the sequence in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The precise question was answered by @scott. Take a look at [git's homepage](http://git-scm.com), it references several books, a bunch of good tutorials, and a lot of other resources. It is a bit tricky to use (specially if you are accustomed to SVN or some other centralized version constrol system), so I'd suggest you set up a few repositories for experimentation (not that git looses information; it *can* do so if you ask forcefully enough, though; it is that the *user* can get confused enough that they don't know how to untangle the mess). Don't be shy in having several copies of the repository on your machine, perhaps an "official" one and others to try out possibly dangerous stuff. OTOH, you can create those on the fly (git operations, even cloning a full repository, are uncannily *fast*).